# Create dynamic google maps link from address fields

Tags: php, html, maps

Let's say I am building out a list of location for a website, and each location has a field for:

- company name
- address
- city
- state

.. And I want to create a direct link to google maps without having to go and grab the link code for every location. How would I accomplish something like this? I am thinking along the lines of:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/#!q=$companyname,$address,$city,$state">Google Map</a>
```

That's just rough syntax (this will probably be php), but I am curious if there is a format similar to that that google maps can read and use.

- Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Try this to embed:

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?parameters`

or your own solution works fine too, for just referring to the maps site:

`http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003`

For more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I am actually trying to create a link that will go to 'maps.google.com/....', not embed a map in my page. Any ideas?

Comment: Your own solution would work perfectly fine in that case. http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003 <- like this.+1 for your own solution. :)

Comment: Oh well check that out. Thanks for the affirmation :)

Comment: np, edited the answer just in case someone is having the same problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

**It is very difficult to create dynamic map using different addresses.But also possible without extension.**

```
 $company_name = "Cybernician";
 $address = "56/14,ShaheenBagh,AbulFazal Enc-II,Jamia Nagar-110025";
 $city ="Delhi";
 $state = "Delhi";

 $company_name = str_replace(' ', '%20', $company_name);
 $map_address = $address.' '.$city.' '.$state.' '.'India';
 $map_address = str_replace(' ','%20',str_replace(',', ' ', $map_address));
 $map_address = str_replace('&','and',str_replace('%20%20','%20',$map_address));
```

**Filter as much as possible to remove unwanted symbol like '&' and others
finally use this code**

```
<div style="width: 330px;margin-left: 15px;"><iframe width="330" height="220" src="http://regiohelden.de/google-maps/map_en.php?width=330&amp;height=220&amp;hl=en&amp;q=<?php echo $map_address; ?>+(<?php echo $company_name; ?>)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=9&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><a href="http://www.regiohelden.de/google-maps/">Google Maps Script</a> von <a href="http://www.regiohelden.de/">RegioHelden</a></iframe><br /><span style="font-size: 7px;"><a href="http://www.regiohelden.de/google-maps/" style="font-size: 7px;">Google Maps Script</a> by <a href="http://www.regiohelden.de/" style="font-size: 7px;">RegioHelden</a></span></div></div>
```